# Sound cuts out after ~20s

Tags: sound

I'm having a strange issue where my sound works perfectly (through my headphones) for ~20 seconds. Then the sound just cuts out and everything is silent. If I close the laptop, let it go to sleep, and then reopen it, the sound will come back, but then will cut out after ~20 seconds. Anyone else face a similar issue? I should add that I just tested the sound with the speakers (no headphones), and I run into the same issue, except the sound lasted for only ~5 seconds.